# URL location differences in script between one host to another

Tags: php, parsing, http-headers

I have the following function that retrieves an image from a twitter feed, the parameter "url" is fed a url such as the following:

```
'http://t.co/ilGWtpkV'
```

Because this is a shortened url, the script then returns the location of that url:

```
http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?pid=1425727&l=1f2c2b6432&id=358116934207463
```

The script then parses out the html contents of this page, and returns the source of url elements by tag.

This is a working example of the script:
http://psuprob.herobo.com/pullmeme.php

In this example the images are compared with the entries via time-stamp to the entries existing in the database, if there are no entries with the same time-stamp, they are added, otherwise, they are not.

This is the function that is used:

```
getImages('http://t.co/ilGWtpkV');

function getImages($url) {
  $url1 = $url;
  require_once('../scripts/simple_html_dom.php'); 
  require_once('../scripts/url_to_absolute.php');

  $response = get_headers($url, 1);
  //Get the location property of the first response header. 
     (returns: http://fb.me/1dnoCICkf)
  $location = $response["Location"];
  $url3 = $location;

  $response2 = get_headers($url3,1);
  //Get the location property of the second response header.
     (returns: the full facebook url)
  $location2 = $response2["Location"];
  $url4 = $location2;

  //image parser
  if(isset($response2["Location"])) { //tests to make sure url is present
  $html = file_get_html($url3);  //function call to return page as html elements

  foreach($html->find('img') as $element) { //finds every img as element
    $bump = url_to_absolute($url4, $element->src);  //converts src to absolute url
      return $bump;
    } 
  }
  else {
    echo "url is not valid (Probably not an image)";
  }

}
```

This function works perfectly on 000webhost servers, however on godaddy's servers, it returns NULL. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use cURL on GoDaddy server to get pages, it is necessary for you to specify their proxy server, like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE,CURLPROXY_HTTP);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PROXY,'http://proxy.shr.secureserver.net:3128');
```

Comment: I'm not using curl to return the html, I'm using file_get_contents, unless there is something I'm missing.

Comment: You checked? file_get_contents works normally on GoDaddy? If not -  Especially try cUrl, file_get_contents doesn't support a proxy, besides it much more slowly than cUrl.

Comment: Yeah, that is unfortunate that godaddy requires a proxy. And I have looked. I probably will change it to cURL